# Amazon EC2 for WCF Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows-services, wcf, amazon-ec2, basichttpbinding

I have a Sync Services built using .Net WCF, .net 4.0,SQL Server 2008 and hosted in a windows service.

Following are some custom implementation we have done;

1. Custom DB Connection Pooling, filled on the start of Application, and there is a cleanup thread as well which runs through out the life cycle of application.
2. Custom Sessions, as application was not targeted to be deployed on IIS and BasicHTTPBinding was used therefore custom session were implemented. Hence a Cleaup thread also runs to clear non-active sessions.
3. [Specific Table] Cache, There is a specific table in database which used to hit with a high frequency therefore we implemented a custom cache to avoid too many hits to database, this cache initiates at the start of Application.

With consideration of above points please Suggest me Following;

1. Is this application suitable to be deployed on IIS? (I thought application deployed on IIS, remains alive only in activity and stops when it gets idle, so caching, pooling will be lost and re-initialize)
2. Is Amazon EC2 is suitable for this; OR I should sign-up for EC2 windows Instance? please brief me on this(I have never used ec2 before nor having much information about it)
3. Is fail-over clustering is supported?
4. Is there any option for Demo Account?
5. What about Windows Azure should i consider that too?

Regards

Comment: I'm interested in the answers on the questions too. Basically I wanna run a WCF service in the cloud.

Comment: We have purchased a windows instance and it runs 247, and deployed the service as windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this application suitable to be deployed on IIS?

If the idle timeout is the reason you avoided IIS then I would say reconsider because you can disable it:
[How to disable the application pool idle time-out in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596267/how-to-disable-the-application-pool-idle-time-out-in-iis7)

And if it's warm up you're worried about it's been addressed in IIS8.0
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

And there's even a "Warm Up" module for IIS 7.5
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization

> Is Amazon EC2 is suitable for this

You could run that fairly easily on either EC2 or Azure Virtual Machines. I'm not sure what you mean by "Amazon EC2 is suitable for this; OR I should sign-up for EC2 windows Instance?", An EC2 instance is just a virtual machine with whatever choice of Operating system you want.

> Is fail-over clustering is supported?

For the web services? You use Amazon Auto Scaling and Load Balancers to maintain a certain number of servers at a time using a simple http healthcheck.
http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/

> Is there any option for Demo Account?

AWS does have a Free Tier which is just enough resources to test and learn.
http://aws.amazon.com/free/
Just note that usage is by hours, for example you get 750 Micro instance hours per month, which means you could run 3 servers for 250 hours.

> What about Windows Azure should i consider that too?

Yes. It's not as flexible as AWS, and misses some features, but Azure should have everything you need for your use case, and may work out slightly cheaper, and is easier to configure for Windows VMs.