# SessionState Timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this setting in the web.config file: `<sessionState timeout="540" />`. This tries to make all the sessions expires after 8 hours. However, the session expires much faster than that and I got an object reference not set to an instance of an object error. Could some tell me if there is something else affects the session?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which SessionStateProvider are you using? How many web servers do you have/use for the application? Are you using the same browser on the same computer? Is anything clearing cookies before your session(s) expire and does the browser remain open throughout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SessionState expires also if the application pool recycles (inactivity, exception, or configuration).

Anyway, it is not a best practice to extend the SessionState timeout so much.

maybe you should change you dependency to session or use a different way to persist those objects (viewstate).

If you absolutely need to have session to persist so much you should use another server or a db as session store.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: If you want to disable the IIS app pool time-out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596267/how-to-disable-the-application-pool-idle-time-out-in-iis7