# Quartz.Net job doesn't fire continuously

Tags: quartz.net

I have a job scheduled in Application_start event using quartz.net, the trigger is fired every 1 min given by the variable repeatDurationTestData = "0 0/1 * * * ?"; 
The triggering starts when I first open the site, But stops after some random time when I close the browser and starts again when I open the site. Following is the code

```
 IMyJob testData = new SynchronizeTestData();
 IJobDetail jobTestData = new JobDetailImpl("Job", "Group", testData.GetType());
 ICronTrigger triggerTestData = new CronTriggerImpl("Trigger", "Group", repeatDurationTestData);
 _scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobTestData, triggerTestData);
 DateTimeOffset? nextFireTime = triggerTestData.GetNextFireTimeUtc();
```

What Am i doing wrong here, Is this because of some misfire. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly your app is shuting down when idle - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306380/can-you-prevent-your-asp-net-application-from-shutting-down

Comment: thanks sgmoore that works for me too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At First I would use a simple trigger in this case as it takes a repeat interval and seems to fit better than the cron trigger would ([from lesson 5](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/TutorialLesson05) quartz.net website) :

```
SimpleTrigger trigger2 = new SimpleTrigger("myTrigger",
                            null,
                            DateTime.UtcNow,
                            null,
                            SimpleTrigger.RepeatIndefinitely,
                            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
```

I would also recommend you don't put the quartz scheduler within the website.  the main purpose of a job system is to work independently of anyother system so it generally fits naturally into a windows service.  By putting it as part of the website you arn't guaranteed its going to keep going.  If you loose the app pool or it restarts, you wont get a reliable result.

There is an example with the quartz.net download.

hope that helps.