# IIS ASP Application Startup Speed

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have an Rest API that is hosted in IIS8. The API is not called very frequently, perhaps 30 times per day. It seems that when the API is called it takes quite a while to get the first result, subsequent calls a short time later return very quickly. It seems that IIS is releasing resources and unloading the API and resources after a period of time.

Is there a way to force IIS to keep API up and active so that every time a request comes it responds quickly?

Comment: try to configure your application pool in iis

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways are mentioned here - [Can you prevent your ASP.NET application from shutting down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306380/can-you-prevent-your-asp-net-application-from-shutting-down)

Other then that there is Application Initialization module http://iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-initialization. Application Initialization module makes sure your process is up and running and loaded with all the necessary libraries, however it works only on IIS 7.5 and greater and framework 4.0 and above.