# Why asp.net web api request taking time for first time?

Tags: azure, web-services, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

Why asp.net web api request taking time for first time? I'm new in asp.net web services and I have published my web service to Azure Cloud and a problem is:

After some time or a day when I call api for first time, it takes much time to response. After that it works fine.

I have explore some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9474978/6426192) but not happy for that.
How can I fix it.
Is this a problem of Asp.net web api or Azure cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: after a while of inactivity, the application running your website/API is shut down. It will only start back up as soon as a new request comes in, but the initial start takes some time.

> if your site doesn’t keep being viewed, your application pool may recycle, and that important visitor number 1 gets screwed waiting as your site rebuilds or your app pool to fire up.

Source: [Keep your ASP.Net websites warm and fast 24/7](https://dougrathbone.com/blog/2010/05/06/keep-your-aspnet-websites-warm-and-fast-247)

In Azure, make sure to **enable Always On**. This is a setting that helps prevent slow startups of web applications:

> By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous WebJobs or runs WebJobs triggered using a CRON expression, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.

Source: [Configure web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure)