# First call to backend (WebAPi) is really slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

- I have a simple web api using .Net framework 4.5 and Entity Framework.
- The problem is **the first call to the backend (WebAPI) is really slow**.
- I had found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811537/why-asp-net-web-api-request-taking-time-for-first-time) **use Application warm up** setting but in my IIS Version 10 I cannot find that setting:

[image]

Does anyone have another solution or idea's? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/applicationinitialization/

Comment: Cold start slowness can be caused by tons of factors, so before doing anything serious, learn a .NET profiler and use it to identify the actual bottleneck. Blind bid on possible causes only waste more time.

Comment: In the IIS, go to `AppPool-> Advanced Settings`. Set `StartMode to AlwaysRunning`. Increase `Idle Time-out minutes` as per your requirements. Go to `your_site-> Advanced Settings`. Set `Preload Enabled to True`. If the issue persists, do you need to inform us whether your application gets shut down or you restart the machine and start facing the issue while calling the site the first time?

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is used caching for same type of data used in whole application which will reduce time of execution and in your problem statement there might be issue with shutting down of server when there is inactivity of request...

Answer (score -1):

you can use Lazy load for performance
for next time loading you can use caching  for example if you use stored procedure you can use

```
OFFSET @skip ROWS FETCH NEXT @PageCount ROWS ONLY
```